# How do font ID algorithms work?

Tags: algorithm, fonts

I was wondering how automatic font identification services (like [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), not question-based ones like [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/)) work. The most basic variant would be a service that lets you upload an image that contains text, and the service returns the name of the font used. How is this done, and how is it done so fast as to be practical? I'm fairly new to this kind of thing, but here's my understanding so far:

- Perhaps some pre-processing to reduce noise. I'm not particularly interested in this part.
- First the image is run through an OCR to extract the text – simple enough.
- Then you go through every font in the tens/hundreds-of-thousands in your database and render the text you have extracted in each one, seeing if it's close to the original. Adjusting for size, alignment, kerning, different weights or italics, etc. *How is this possibly fast enough to be practical?*

Is this correct?

Please offer some insight into how this is done, and how it's done efficiently.

Comment: The magic of machine learning :) check out classifiers and maybe the ellipsoid algorithm for starters.

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume you are doing the match in the raster representation (not on vectorized outlines).

Indeed, the text should be recognized first to reduce the number of comparisons with the characters in the reference fonts; at this stage it matters to avoid any dubious recognition as this would wreak havoc.

Then a stage of normalization is needed: you can transform the character position, size (and possibly italics angle ?) to a standard bounding box so that pixel-by-pixel comparison becomes possible. Then the amount of computation will be proportional to the area of the characters times the number of reference fonts.

Beware that normalization in size is not fully accurate as big character shrunk will differ from a smaller character in the same font in a few details and stroke thickness. It is probably useful to consider two or three representative sizes per font.

Comment: Interesting about the italics (I just remembered that browsers can "fake" a font's italics style, so software could probably do it in reverse). But if you have so many fonts in your database and the time is proportional to that, then how is it so darn *fast*? Give a try to WhatTheFont, it's incredible.

Comment: Assume 20 characters, 30x20 pixels each, against 1000 fonts. That is 12,000,000 pixel comparisons/accumulations. Computable in less than a 10th of a second, and can be SIMD accelerated.